# Excel 2016 blank cell read as 0

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a conditional statement:  `IF('Res11'!I21="","",IF('Res11'!I21="X","X",VLOOKUP(ROUND('Res11'!I21/IF('Res11'!J21="",'Res11'!I$20,'Res11'!J21)*15,0),TABLE2,2,FALSE)))`

This is not a new spreadsheet and it did work perfectly.

Now it is reading the blank cell as containing a 0 and returning a division by 0 error.

Is this new in Excel 2016?

How can I fix it?

This occurs in many spreadsheets that are quite large.

Comment: Please shorten your formula and post only the part which gives the error. It's not clear from your question which cell is `""` and gives the wrong `0` result.

Comment: Posting a screen shot would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> division by 0 error.

is due to

```
ROUND('Res11'!I21/IF('Res11'!J21="",'Res11'!I$20,'Res11'!J21)*15,0)
```

of your formula. It is a possible cause to division by zero.

Alternatively, you may wrap it iferror() to force "blank" if error like this :

```
iferror(IF('Res11'!I21="","",IF('Res11'!I21="X","X",VLOOKUP(ROUND('Res11'!I21/IF('Res11'!J21="",'Res11'!I$20,'Res11'!J21)*15,0),TABLE2,2,FALSE))),"")
```